# How can i monitor cfthread processes?

Tags: coldfusion

Now that I am using it for backend processing of csv files, and the cf8 standard is limited to ten threads, I want to make sure i won't somehow overload the server...

Any suggestions?

I am making uniquely named threads, but i am worried about performance...also what if i need to stop a thread, how do i do that?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColdFusion 9's Server Monitor will allow you to measure server performance such as Memory, Requests and specific Threads. Prior to ColdFusion 9 you needed to use third party utilities such as FusionReactor to monitor threads ([www.fusion-reactor.com](http://www.fusion-reactor.com)). While I have not used FusionReactor, it does have a good reputation in the CF community.

Comment: But the company I work with, has cf8, with perfmon not working. So what other ways that cost nothing, can i list what threads are currently in progress, and how can i disable them?

Comment: The following link applies to ColdFusion 8 monitoring. It may not apply to the non-Enterprise edition. 

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/monitoring_pt2_02.html

Answer (score 1):

In the Administrator settings, you can change how many of your available threads are used for background processing.  The setting is at the bottom of the Request Tuning page.

Comment: I'm running CF8 Standard, and have mine set to 8.  Odd.  I'm assuming you have your own server (VPS, dedicated, whatever) and full access to the Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Log into the ColdFusion Administrator Server Monitor. Select the "Statistics" tab, and choose "Active ColdFusion Threads" under the "Request Statistics" menu. From there you can see what threads are running, and you can stop them by clicking the red "Abort Request" symbol to the left of the thread name. That will let you keep an eye on running threads and you can tune from there.

Comment: Any coldfusion tags or code i can use to see running threads?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to monitor threads, unless you have the server monitor on, and for cf8 standard that is disabled.

There's no way, I could find to list active threads, in a query or java code...

Which would be an important improvement, to have some kind of tracking mechanism.

I can't make a solution for something that is not available to me in information or statistics.

Thank You all for your effrots.

Answer (score -1):

```
td = createObject('java', 'coldfusion.monitor.util.CFthreadDictionary');
writedump(td.getInstance().getAllActiveThreads());
```